# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClasses_enhancedWithInstantReloadDexForDebug'

Tags: java, android, gradle, dex

I started having problems recently, when trying to build I get this error.

**Error**

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClasses_enhancedWithInstantReloadDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process

**Gradle**

```
...

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.appsss.android"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        jniDebuggable true
        debuggable true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    release {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```